# Add bottom border line to the edit text widget

Tags: android, widget, textedit

I want to add a bottom border line to the edit text widget like in a material design, but i cant find way to do it.
Thanks for helpers
EDIT:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: Please provide the details of what you wants to do and what you tried for that. it will help people to answer your question fast.

Answer (score 0):

Get a 9patch image [This site might help you produce them](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and apply it as the background resource for your edit text

```
android:background="@drawable/9patchname"
```

[image]

Alternatively you can fake it with a separate view below the edit text

```
<style name="divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/grey</item>
</style>


<View style="@style/divider" />
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to make only bottom stroke

Comment: This can be done with 9patches similar to the one I added above - the website i linked will help you create them in various colours too

Comment: This type saw, it the default one, but i maked the edittext full width
and changed the background to white and the default line is gone and i need to make a flat bottom line.
Sorry for that i didnt wrote it in the question.

Comment: Remove the edges on the line in the 9patch should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

[image: ADD THIS IMAGE TO YOUR EDITTEXT]

```
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/input_text_bg"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```